# Android listener for shared elements animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am working with shared element animations.

I have a RecyclerView with an ImageView. If I click on one of the list items, another activity is started

```
 Intent activityIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Activity.class);
 ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, imageview, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageview));
 startActivity(activityIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Everything works as expected but I am wondering whether there is something similar to a listener for the animation. I have a CollapsedToolbarLayout and the shared element animation always flies over the title of my toolbar. I would like to set the title after the animation. Is that possible?

Comment: see `android.transition.Transition` API documentation

Comment: But how can I grap the Transition from `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`?